# Android Studio 3.0.1 Unable to delete file

Tags: android-studio-3.0

Android Studio 3.0.1
Java 1.8

Sometimes(not always) when I try to run (`Shift-F10`) my application I get error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
> Unable to delete file: D:\myproject\app\build\intermediates\processing-tools\runtime-deps\debug\desugar_try_with_resources.jar
```

I need to clean and rebuild project to fix this. The rebuild is too long (about 7 minutes). It's not very good.

So I want to avoid this error? How I can do this?